# DNS resolving troubles in 19.10

Tags: networking, dns, 19.10

I recently upgraded to 19.10. From time to time, I see that DNS is not resolving properly e.g. within Firefox or Thunderbird. Trying the same request in another tab will yield the same result. Trying the same URL immediately in a private tab (while the other tabs are still hanging), resolves the site normally. Other URLs are still resolved without any issue while the other URLs are still hanging to be resolved.

After a few seconds, the effect goes away and everything is back to normal for all URLs and all protocols.

This happens ~10-15 times seemingly randomly per work day currently. It's also happening for IMAP connections or SSH connections.

Using wireshark, I see lot's of ICMP Destination unrechable towards my router when the issue is happening. I also recently updated the router to its latest firmware (Asus RT-AC68U). Logs reveal nothing at this time. Connection is over Cat6/ethernet.

My DNS resolver is using a symlinked resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Edit:
My current /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as         published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes

ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=1.29 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=1.05 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=1.11 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=1.12 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.046/1.136/1.288/0.080 ms

www.ebay.com is an alias for slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net has address 23.211.5.229
```